# Lightweight lock using OMP atomic

Tags: multithreading, locking, openmp, fortran

I am working on a Monte Carlo simulation using OpenMP multithreading. To avoid race conditions when multiple threads work on the same resolution element, I have implemented the following `module` to atomically (using OMP `atomic`, since AFAIK there's no easy way to do atomic operations directly in Fortran) acquire and release a lock:

```
module portability
  use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: al=ATOMIC_LOGICAL_KIND
end module portability

module atomic_lock
  use portability
  implicit none
contains

  subroutine acquire_atomic_lock(have_lck, lck, error, blocking)
    logical(al), intent(inout) :: have_lck
    logical(al), intent(inout) :: lck

    integer, intent(out), optional :: error

    logical(al), intent(in), optional :: blocking

    logical(al) :: lck_copy, blk
    integer :: err

    if(present(blocking)) then
       blk = blocking
    else
       blk = .true.
    endif

    lck_copy = .true.
    err = 0
    if(have_lck) then
       ! already have a lock, can not acquire new one
       err = 1
    else
       if(blk) then
          ! PROBLEM: busy waiting here
          do while(lck_copy)
             !$omp atomic capture
             lck_copy = lck
             lck = .true.
             !$omp end atomic
          end do
          have_lck = .true.
       else
          !$omp atomic capture
          lck_copy = lck
          lck = .true.
          !$omp end atomic
          have_lck = .not. lck_copy
       end if
    end if

    if(present(error)) then
       error = err
    end if
  end subroutine acquire_atomic_lock

  subroutine release_atomic_lock(have_lck, lck, error)
    logical(al), intent(inout) :: have_lck
    logical(al), intent(inout) :: lck

    integer, intent(out), optional :: error

    logical(al) :: lck_copy
    integer :: err

    err = 0
    if(.not. have_lck) then
       ! can not release a lock we do not have
       err = 1
    else
       !$omp atomic capture
       lck_copy = lck
       lck = .false.
       !$omp end atomic

       if(.not. lck_copy) then
          ! lock was released while we thought we had it
          err = 2
       end if
    end if

    if(present(error)) then
       error = err
    end if
  end subroutine release_atomic_lock
end module atomic_lock
```

Here's an MWE:

```
program main
  use portability
  use atomic_lock
  use omp_lib
  implicit none

  logical(al) :: lock_sum, have_lock
  integer :: sum
  integer :: nthreads=4

  call omp_set_num_threads(nthreads)

  lock_sum = .false.
  have_lock = .false.
  sum = 0

  !$omp parallel default(none) shared(lock_sum, sum) firstprivate(have_lock)
  call acquire_atomic_lock(have_lock, lock_sum)

  sum = sum + omp_get_thread_num()

  call release_atomic_lock(have_lock, lock_sum)
  !$omp end parallel

  write(*,*) sum == (nthreads*(nthreads-1))/2
end program main
```

It works well even with 20000 or so threads on my four core processor and is, unsurprisingly, much faster than using OMP `critical` instead of `atomic`.

However, I would still like to know what shortcomings you can identify in my implementation and how you would fix them. One problem I see and don't know how to fix is that `acquire_atomic_lock` does busy waiting if the lock isn't available. In my case this will not be a huge problem, I presume, since I have many more resolution elements than threads and consequently collisions will be unlikely but it would be nice to fix it anyway.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! That seems to be a great question and I hope you get good feedback as well.

Comment: This is quite an advanced code (from the point of OpenMP) so it will be harder to find good advice. The Fortran itself is written nicely.

Comment: @VladimirF thank you, I'm glad to hear that. I was hoping an OMP expert could maybe give me some insight on how to solve the busy waiting problem. Let's see.

Comment: Too bad this never got an answer. I guess the first thing I’d wonder is, is it possible to use something like RCU, so that there is never any need to lock either the precious state or the upcoming state?